# RegEx with notepad++: Remove two groups of text

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have this string on a line:

`('some text', 'some text', 'some text', '{\n  {\n  {\n . <p>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br></p> \n} \n} \n}', 'some text' , 'some text')`

and i would to have this result using RegEx with notepad++:

`('some text', 'some text', 'some text', '<p>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br></p>', 'some text' , 'some text')`

Is it possible? Someone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: Is it literally `\n` or a linefeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `{.+?(?=<)|(?<=>)[^<>]+}`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  {         # opening brace
  .+?       # 1 or more any character but newline
  (?=<)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have < after
|         # OR
  (?<=>)    # positive lookbehind, make sure we have > before
  [^<>]+    # 1 or more any character that is not < or >
  }         # closing brace
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. I tried to use just te part before "|" and it works. So the problem is on the second part of the expression

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply use the OR(|) operator between the two groups you want to remove, and cancel out the backslashes with a backslash

```
({\\n  {\\n  {\\n .)|( \\n} \\n} \\n})
```

in the replace tab, and select the regular expressions search mode